# clearInterval() what happens with the last interval call

Tags: javascript

```
var interval = setInterval(function()
                { function }, 1000);

 clearInterval(interval);
```

What happens with the last interval call when clearInterval is called? If the interval is 500 out of 1000 (.5 seconds) into the interval and clearInterval is called, does this function get called and then the interval is cancelled? Or does the function not get called and the interval is cancelled?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the specified interval hasn't yet elapsed, the callback will not be invoked again. The standard isn't clear on what would happen if the interval has elapsed but the callback has not yet been processed by the event queue, but in the case where there are 500 ms remaining before the next invocation, it definitely shouldn't invoke the callback again.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it out with something like:

```
var counter = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() { 
  console.log(counter); 
  counter++;
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, 5900);

=> 0
=> 1
```

As you can see, if the interval is interrupted midway, the callback won't be executed.